# Arch Linux doesnt open Firefox

Tags: firefox, archlinux

When I try to open Firefox through terminal by typing firefox nothing happens.  Also there are no logs coming up. Also nothing appears in journalctn.

Comment: Can you type `which firefox` in the terminal? Or `type firefox`? Perhaps there's an alias or rogue binary taking precedence over `firefox` in your PATH?

Comment: type firefox shows /usr/bin/firefox

Comment: On my Arch box, where FF is working fine, `firefox` on the command line results in no output by default. Maybe if you run `firefox --help` you'll at least see some output to show the binary is intact? If that works, maybe try something like `firefox --safemode`? On my install `/usr/bin/firefox` is just a bash script that launches `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`. Maybe try running `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` and see if that helps? Or `ldd /usr/lib/firefox/firefox` to see if any libraries are missing?

Comment: is there anything in `dmesg`?